# How to delete a particular view on the click of button in a ListView in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I have made a custom view that consists of two text views and one button. I just want when i click on the button then the respective view is gone and list adjust itselt.
here is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.dv.deletev;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;
    String name[]={"Ankit","Arora","Arun","yadav"};
    String no[]={"AnAnaAN","cccc","bbbbb","aaa"};
    static CustomAdapter obj;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        obj=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,name,no);

        lv.setAdapter(obj);
    //obj.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public static  CustomAdapter take()
    {
        return obj;
    }
}
```

### CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.dv.deletev;

import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.dv.deletev.*;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

String name[];
String no[];
    Context con;
    MainActivity a;
    public CustomAdapter(Context con,String a[],String b[])
    {
        super(con,R.layout.second,a);
        name=a;
        this.con=con;   
        no=b;
        }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater lv=(LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView=lv.inflate(R.layout.second, null);

    TextView tv1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Button  bt=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);      
        final List<String> arr1;
        final List<String> arr2;
        arr1=(List<String>) Arrays.asList(name);
        arr2=(List<String>) Arrays.asList(no);

        final ArrayList<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>(arr1);
        final ArrayList<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>(arr2);


    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

        arr.remove(position);
        ar.remove(position);
        a.take().notifyDataSetChanged();

        //CustomAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();}

        }
    });
        tv1.setText(name[position]);
        tv2.setText(no[position]);

        return convertView;
    }







}
```

### Second.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:text="Button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </RelativeLayout>


activity_main.xml
-----------------
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.dv.deletev.MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

there is no such problem on logic part everything works fine, ListView appeared is what i wanted but on the click of button nothing happens.
Any suggestions...?

Comment: There are `>1k` such a questions available in SO. Search on _Google_

Comment: where assigned button in your code?

Comment: you have posted for both MainActivity and CustomAdaptrer the same code

Comment: no, I didn't. They both are in separate files

Comment: Only a suggestion not related to your question: choose better names for your variables. In future could happen that someone will use your code and will have a lot of difficulties to understand it.

Comment: @MD I came here from Google.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems in this code, sorry if i will seem salty, i fixed only some necessary things:

1. two arrays of string with same length passed in an adapter. It's better to use a custom object that wraps these two string instead of two arrays
2. the transformation to arraylist without any purpose
3. the reference to the adapter from activity context instead from the adapter itself
4. the confusion about use arrays items but remove lists items
5. the code indentation
6. the code variable's name

---

```
package com.dv.deletev;

import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.dv.deletev.*;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

String name[];
String no[];
    Context con;
    MainActivity a;
    //declare them global
    ArrayList<String> arr;
    ArrayList<String> ar;
    public CustomAdapter(Context con,String a[],String b[])
    {
        super(con,R.layout.second,a);
        name=a;
        this.con=con;   
        no=b;
        // initialize them in constructor
        arr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(name));
        ar = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(no);
        }



    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater lv=(LayoutInflater) con.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView=lv.inflate(R.layout.second, null);

    TextView tv1=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView tv2=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    Button  bt=(Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.button1);      

    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

        arr.remove(position);
        ar.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

        //don't use reference of the adapter itself from the activity
        //a.take().notifyDataSetChanged();

        //CustomAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();}

        }
    });
        // set them to list
        tv1.setText(arr.get(position));
        tv2.setText(ar.get(positon));

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, there are problems in the code but your solution didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You convert the array to a list and remove the list item but you don't convert the list back to the array, so the remove is lost.

`ArrayAdapter` already has a `remove()` method, you should just use that.